# PHP return size of Wordpress Articles

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to make Wordpress return the length of my articles in 3 categories: Small, Medium and Large.

I'm currently using this function to test it but I doesn't seem to work (I'm a total PHP noob!)

```
function wcount(){
ob_start();
the_content();
$content = ob_get_clean();
    if ($content > 4000) {
        return 'large';
    } else if ($content > 2500) {
        return 'medium';
    } else {
        return 'small';
    }
}
```

Could anyone please help me? It would be even better if the function automatically added the post to the right category in Wordpress, but for now this was all I could.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `strlen($content)` <- your friend.

Comment: I'd like to remind you I'm a total PHP noob. I copied most of this code from some tutorial.

Comment: I added you an answer with a link and an example, should be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`strlen`](http://php.net/strlen) function to get the length of a string:

```
function wcount()
{
    ob_start();
    the_content();
    $content = ob_get_clean();
    $length = strlen($content);
    if ($length > 4000) return 'large';
    if ($length > 2500) return 'medium';
    return 'small';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, how would I place this in my WP loop? <?php echo $wcount; ?> Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Try `<?php echo wcount(); ?>` instead. It's a function, not a variable.